# Copying files after accidental removal of various packages

Tags: apt, 18.04, usb, ssh, data-recovery

I have accidentally deleted a number of packages using `apt remove` (I accidentally included an asterisk in the package name I was actually trying to remove), and now my system is not working in a number of different ways. So, I am going to re-install Ubuntu. However, there are some files in my home directory which I need to copy first.

But one of the problems that has arisen since the accidental removal of packages, is that I cannot log in to Ubuntu's GUI. The only way I can log in is through TTY. Using this, I can find the files that I need to copy.

So there are two ways that I can think of to copy these files. Either, I would ssh into a different machine and copy them using scp, or I would copy them onto a removable USB memory stick. After the accidental removal though, neither of these work...

When I try to ssh into a different machine, I receive a message saying `ssh: Could not resolve hostname x.x.x.x: Temporary failure in name resolution`. But this was working before I messed things up. I have checked and both openssh-server and openssh-client are still installed. I have also noticed that if I try `ping www.google.com`, I receive a similar message: `ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

And when I try to copy to a removable USB memory stick, nothing shows up in `/media` or `/mnt`. Both of these directories are completely empty. I have tried this with two different memory sticks.

Can anybody suggest how to solve either of these two problems, or alternatively, suggest another way in which I can copy these files before I re-install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your system probably can be rescued because your package system still should be in a healthy state, try rescuing/saveguarding your user files first if you do not have an up to date backup. to that aim, **start the machine up with a Live Ubuntu CD or USB**. You will then have a working live session on this PC, allowing you automatically have removable media mounted when you plug them in. You will also need to mount the partition on your internal drive where your files reside. Here, it should be sufficient to click the drive icon in the left pane of the file manager that represents the partition. Subsequently, you can copy files.

Once you safeguarded your user files, you can attempt repairing the system. Since you just removed too much in a "correct" way, i.e., using `apt`, your package system should still be OK. As your system does not anymore work correctly, you very likely also removed the `ubuntu-desktop` package. Reinstalling that metapackage should automatically pull back in all packages that make up a default Ubuntu desktop and thus make your system fully operational again.

Log back in to a text console and issue the following command to reinstall the ubuntu-desktop package

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks, these are great suggestions. So, I tried `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`, and this then printed out all the packages it was going to install, but then it got stuck on `connecting to security.ubuntu.com` and nothing else happened. Is this some kind of Catch 22 where I need internet access to be able to install the packages for internet access...?

Comment: I then tried your idea of using a Live Ubuntu USB. This enabled me to get into the Ubuntu GUI. But how do I now access the original hard drive? If I just go to `/home`, the only directory in there is `/home/ubuntu`, i.e. the live Ubuntu.

Comment: Edited my answer: internal partition also needs to be mounted. If all goes well, an icon for it should be present in the left pane of the file manager. You may not have write permissions as normal user, but as long as you see the files, you can copy them.

Comment: Thanks. I tried just clicking on the icon, and this gave the following error: `Unable to access "Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS amd64" Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS amd64: /dev/sdc1 already mounted or mount point busy`. So it seems that my hard drive, `sdc1`, cannot be mounted... I also tried doing this from the command line, with `sudo mkdir /media/harddrive` and `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/harddrive`, but this returned a similar message: `mount: /media/newhd: /dev/sdc1 already mounted or mount point busy.`

Comment: Also, if I click the hard drive's "eject" button on the desktop panel, it prints out: `Unable to eject Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS amd64. Cannot eject drive in use: Device /dev/sdc is mounted`. I'm wondering if this icon is actually the live Ubuntu, rather than my hard drive...?

Comment: Ah, I have solved it. I had to go into "Other Locations", and one of the volumes listed there is my hard drive. I have now been able to copy the files. Thank you very much!